# Laravel 8 JetStream BindingResolutionException Target class [App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests] does not exist

Tags: routes, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream, inertiajs

These setting up a new laravel8 project with jetStream InertiaJs, but when I start the application I get the following error:

[image]

Apparently it is a route error and the blogs show the solution to edit the RouteServiceProvider.php file and define the following variable:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

```
$this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
```

The web file paths are as follows:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
        'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),
        'canRegister' => Route::has('register'),
        'laravelVersion' => Application::VERSION,
        'phpVersion' => PHP_VERSION,
    ]);
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

but the error remains, please someone can tell me a solution or that I should review to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to `use Inertia\Inertia;` at top of the PHP file before using it.

Answer (score 3):

Follow instructions here:
https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup

```
composer require inertiajs/inertia-laravel
php artisan inertia:middleware
```

Then the class should be found. Noticed the class couldn't resolve in the IDE, so assumed it wasn't installed by default out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, you may missed out a backward slash before App.
Put it as below in your web.php file:
`\App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class`